# SKEmitterNode displaying different in emulator and particle editor

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

I'm testing the particle system creating blue fire using "SpriteKit Particle File".
The problem is that when running in the emulator the fire is displayed worse. Here you have the images.

Fire in particle editor:

[image: Fire in particle editor]

Fire in emulator:

[image: Fire in emulator]

This is the code I used to load the particle file

```
    NSString *firePath =
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fire" ofType:@"sks"];

    SKEmitterNode *fire =
    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:firePath];

    fire.position = CGPointMake(240, 110);
    [self addChild:fire];
```

Why is this happening and someone knows how can I resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: The Simulator is not a device, it's not unusual to see it render effects differently (it's a software renderer that doesn't use hardware acceleration so some OpenGL features are prone to be "reduced"). If it looks correct on the device then there is no problem.